# Difference between wait and sleep

Tags: bash, shell, wait, sleep

What is difference between `wait` and `sleep`?

Answer (score 442, accepted):

`wait` waits for a process to finish; `sleep` sleeps for a certain amount of seconds.

Comment: `wait 60` waits for job 60 to finish; `sleep 60` sleeps for 60 seconds.

Comment: `wait 60` should finish immediately with an error message; if not, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 142):

wait is a BASH built-in command.  From `man bash`:

```
    wait [n ...]
        Wait  for each specified process and return its termination sta-
        tus.  Each n may be a process ID or a job  specification;  if  a
        job  spec  is  given,  all  processes in that job's pipeline are
        waited for.  If n is not given, all currently active child  pro-
        cesses  are  waited  for,  and  the return status is zero.  If n
        specifies a non-existent process or job, the  return  status  is
        127.   Otherwise,  the  return  status is the exit status of the
        last process or job waited for.
```

sleep is not a shell built-in command.  It is a utility that delays for a specified amount of time.

The `sleep` command may support waiting in various units of time.  GNU coreutils 8.4 `man sleep` says:

```
    SYNOPSIS
        sleep NUMBER[SUFFIX]...

    DESCRIPTION
        Pause for NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be ‘s’ for seconds (the default),
        ‘m’ for minutes, ‘h’ for hours or ‘d’ for days.  Unlike most  implemen-
        tations  that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbi-
        trary floating point number.  Given two or more  arguments,  pause  for
        the amount of time specified by the sum of their values.
```

Answer (score 115):

`sleep` just delays the shell for the given amount of seconds.

`wait` makes the shell wait for the given job. e.g.:

```
workhard &
[1] 27408
workharder &
[2] 27409
wait %1 %2
```

delays the shell until both of the subprocesses have finished

Comment: IMHO it is `wait %1 %2` or `wait 27408 27409` or simply `wait` if there is no other background process. In this case you are trying to wait for PID 1 (init) and PID 2 ([migration/0] on my Linux), but you will get error message, like: `-bash: wait: pid 1 is not a child of this shell` and returns the exit code `127`.

Comment: So as of 2 Years nobody realized it. You are absolutely right, will edit the answer...