# How to connect to a linux server and stop/start a service using a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to setup a script which will connect to a linux server and then stop/start a service. But between the stop and start of the service, it should wait ~10 seconds and check if the service is really stopped.

```
service httpd stop
--wait 10 seconds. check ps -ef | grep httpd, kill if any hanged processes
service httpd start
```

Please can someone help me on how to do it?

Comment: Use `sleep` and a `kill -9` instead of explicit checking.

Comment: can i connect to the server using the username and password? I am checking in the forms but most of them say create an ssh key. I will deploy this shell script on the same server i want to run the commands

Comment: You certainly can configure the ssh server to accept a password. But that is not recommended, since it is much more insecure than a key. And you can only do that in an interactive manner, so _not_ with a script. At least you should not.

Comment: i am trying sleep but i am getting this error sleep: invalid time interval `10\r', can you tell me how to fix this. this is what i added in the script : sleep 10

Comment: You need change the line break coding in your script. Use Unix-/Linux line breaks in your editor, not MS-Windows style.

Comment: please another question, how do i check if there are hanged process and kill them? if i use kill -9, i am getting error that the command is not complete

Comment: You obviously need to specify _what_ process to kill. Read the man pages of the commands you try to use, if you are unsure about their usage. For example `man kill`. In your case `killall -9 /usr/sbin/httpd` might be a good alternative, since it does not require a specific process id.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: You might want to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use Stack Overflow effectively. In the meantime, maybe [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` command is for a different purpose, we need to use the `sleep` command instead.

Check this link for detailed differences.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296927/3086531

---

Script to check if process is running or not

```
#!/bin/bash
UP=$(pgrep httpd | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
        echo "httpd is down.";
else
        echo "All is well.";
fi
```

---

Your final code would be

```
#!/bin/bash

service httpd stop 

sleep 10 

UP=$(pgrep httpd | wc -l);
if [ "$UP" -ne 1 ];
then
  service httpd start  #start serivce again, since no process are found 
else
  echo "Service is not stopped yet.";
  killall -15 httpd  #Kills all processes related to httpd
  service httpd start #start httpd process
fi
```

Comment: There is no need for this complexity. Why bother to check if there still is a process, you are going to hard kill it anyway. Just fire a `killall -9` without checking and you know all is fine.

Comment: @arkascha, processes should be stopped gracefully. We should allow them to perform clean-up routines (such as removing lock files, flushing in-memory data to hard drives etc.) before terminating.

Comment: Then do a `killall -15` (or simply `killall`) instead of a `killall -9`. That was not my point.

Comment: @arkascha, what's wrong with sending signal 15 (SIGTERM)? It is meant to be handled, while SIGKILL can not be handled by a process.

Comment: How is `wait` deprecated? Its purpose is different from `sleep`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I apologize, My bad.  Corrected it now.

Comment: I already confirmed that SIGTERM is fine and maybe better here. As said: that is not the point I made. I pointed out that it is not necessary to first check if a process still exists. `killall` which just terminate silently if that is _not_ the case. So you can blindly use it.

Comment: @arkascha I agree with what you say, `killall` can terminate process safely.
 
However, my answer is inspired from this 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28265 
which basically states, it's safe to kill daemon applications using `service stop`. Not sure about actual reason or technicalities behind it.

Comment: Actually thinking about this brings me to state that `killall -15` does _not_ make sense. The `stop` command already does that. The OP wants to kill the process in case it hangs. So we are back at `killall -9` which should _not_ find any processes left, but guarantees a clean situation for the `start` command.

Comment: @bhar1red thank you. Can i also do this procedure with other services? Like i have a service called appmanager. service appmanager start and service appmanager stop. I would like to do this same thing with that also. appmanager is a java app that is in /home/mydir/appmanager.jar

Comment: @SaiAvinash In order to run java apps as service, you need to follow this procedure here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203626/3086531 

or here is a simple solution for what you wanted to achieve 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203634/3086531

Comment: @SaiAvinash In order to run java apps as service, you need to follow this procedure here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203626/3086531 

or here is a simple solution for what you wanted to achieve 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203634/3086531